# no matching EC2 Security Group found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I create modules for creating AWS vpc, security group and EC2. I make EC2 module depend on vpc and the security group module.
but I get that error:

```
no matching EC2 Security Group found
  on .terraform/modules/main_ec2/modules/EC2Module/main.tf line 26, in data "aws_security_group" "security_group_id":
  26: data "aws_security_group" "security_group_id" {
```

EC2 module

```
data "aws_subnet" "subnet_id" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  count = length(var.subnet_name)
  depends_on = [var.subnet_id_depends_on]
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["VPC0${var.vpc_number}-${element(var.subnet_name, count.index)}"]
  }
}

data "aws_security_group" "security_group_id" {
  count = length(var.Server_Group_Name)
  depends_on = [var.security_group_depends_on]
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${local.name}-SG-${var.Server_Group_Name[count.index]}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "create_instance" {
  ami = "${element(data.aws_ami_ids.ami_id.*.id, count.index)}"
  instance_type = var.EC2_Type[count.index]
  subnet_id = "${element(data.aws_subnet.subnet_id.*.id, count.index)}"
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ data.aws_security_group.security_group_id[count.index].id ]
  key_name = "${local.name}-KP-${var.Server_Name[count.index]}"
  depends_on = [var.EC2_depends_on]
}
```

sg module

```
resource "aws_security_group" "SGS" {
  count       = length(var.Server_Group_Name)
  name        = "${local.name}-SG-${var.Server_Group_Name[count.index]}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  description = "${local.name}-SG-${var.Server_Group_Name[count.index]}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  tags = {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = "${local.name}-SG-${var.Server_Group_Name[count.index]}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  }
```

varibles.tf

```
variable "subnet_id_depends_on" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["module.vpc_main"]
  
}

variable "security_group_depends_on" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["module.sg"]
  
}
variable "EC2_depends_on" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [ "module.vpc_main", "module.sg", "module.key_pair" ]
}
```

for example, I call modules like that:

```
module "main_ec2" { 
  source = "/home/reham/Data/projectes/terraform//modules/EC2Module" 
  subnet_id_depends_on = var.subnet_id_depends_on 
  security_group_depends_on = var.security_group_depends_on 
  ami_name = var.ami_name 
  EC2_depends_on = var.EC2_depends_on
}
```

Outputs defined in the sg module:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  description = "VPC ID"
  value = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

output "primary_public_subnets_id" {
  description = "public subnet ID"
  value = aws_subnet.primary_public_subnets.*.id
}

output "secondary_public_subnets_id" {
  description = "public subnet ID"
  value = aws_subnet.secondary_public_subnets.*.id
} 

output "primary_private_subnets_id" {
  description = "public subnet ID"
  value = aws_subnet.primary_private_subnets.*.id
}

output "security-groups" {
  value = aws_security_group.SGS[*].id
}
```

what must I do to solve this problem?

Comment: How are you calling the modules?

Comment: Why would you use data source to get info about your SGs? Just output their IDs or what you need from the modules that create them.

Comment: i call module like that
```
module "main_ec2" {
    source  = "/home/reham/Data/projectes/terraform//modules/EC2Module"
    region = var.region
    access_key = var.access_key
    secret_key = var.secret_key
    subnet_id_depends_on = var.subnet_id_depends_on
    security_group_depends_on = var.security_group_depends_on
    ami_name = var.ami_name
    EC2_Type = var.EC2_IP
    EC2_IP = var.EC2_IP
    EC2_depends_on = var.EC2_depends_on
}
```

Comment: how do I call a specific security group from the name from the output?

Comment: Do you get any outputs from the `module.vpc_main`, `module.sg` or `module.key_pair`?

Comment: yes, i get that the output of vpc
output "vpc_id" {
  description = "VPC ID"
  value       = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

output "primary_public_subnets_id" {
  description = "public subnet ID"
  value       = aws_subnet.primary_public_subnets.*.id
}

output "secondary_public_subnets_id" {
  description = "public subnet ID"
  value       = aws_subnet.secondary_public_subnets.*.id
}

output "primary_private_subnets_id" {
  description = "public subnet ID"
  value       = aws_subnet.primary_private_subnets.*.id
}

Comment: and that the output of sg         
output "security-groups" {
  value = aws_security_group.SGS[*].id
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one issue with the code and it is a result of probably not understanding how the module outputs work [1]. The second part of the issue is that there are many explicit dependencies defined with `depends_on` which are not required to be there since implicit dependencies are good enough [2]. Furthermore, as per comments, `data` sources in the EC2 module are not required as information about VPC, subnets and security groups can be provided with the outputs. Additionally, the EC2 instance resource is using `count`, but there is no `count` meta-argument there, so it will not work even if all the inputs are fixed. So here are my suggestions:

1. Redefine variables in the EC2 module (no need for `depdends_on`) and remove data sources (except possibly the one for the AMI)
2. Decide which variable you are going to use for the `count` meta-argument in the EC2 instance resource

I am going to give you an example with one subnet and security groups and then you can build from there. The EC2 module fixes:

```
resource "aws_instance" "create_instance" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami_ids.ami_id[0].id
  instance_type               = var.EC2_Type
  subnet_id                   = var.subnet_id
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = var.security_group_ids
  key_name                    = "${local.name}-KP-${var.Server_Name[0]}"
}
```

In EC2 module, the variables would have to be changed to:

```
variable "subnet_id" {}
variable "security_group_ids" {}
```

Then, in the root module:

```
module "main_ec2" { 
  source             = "/home/reham/Data/projectes/terraform//modules/EC2Module" 
  subnet_id          = module.sg.primary_public_subnets_id[0] 
  security_group_ids = module.sg.security-groups
  ami_name           = var.ami_name 
}
```

Referencing the module outputs in the EC2 module will make sure that the SG module is created first (that is an implicit dependency). At best this should give you a result for one EC2 instance as it seems there are many resources that rely on using the `count` meta-argument and that code is not in the question.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs#accessing-child-module-outputs

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/behavior#resource-dependencies

Comment: Hi, Marko, thank you very much for the helpful answer but the output in state file empty and I have another error (creating EC2 Instance: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The subnet ID 'module.vpc_main.aws_subnet.primary_public_subnets[0].id' does not exist
        status code: 400, request id: 242527f7-b9c5-4219-baf8-e55edd12e017

  on .terraform/modules/main_ec2/modules/EC2Module/main.tf line 65, in resource "aws_instance" "create_instance":
  65: resource "aws_instance" "create_instance" { )

Comment: That seems like a different problem for a different question.